# How to use un-bonded I/O cells in Lattice Diamond Verilog compilers

Tags: verilog, lattice-diamond

just wanted to use some of the delay features (delays, deserialization) in some of the IO cells of a Lattice Mach XO2 chip - any clues how to configure them? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works in an lpf file, but I've just checked and using the `LOC` attribute on a IO buffer works with an unbonded pad given the pad name (which can be found using the Diamond physical view or EPIC) - this is for ECP5; XO2 might be a bit different:

```
(* LOC="PR50A" *)
(* IO_TYPE="LVTTL33" *)
IB i_b(.I(pad), .O(dummy));
```